# A new constant?

Tags: integration, constants

I was experimenting in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) the answer to the equation $\int_0^k x^x dx=1$ And I got about 1.19... But, What is this number **k** (and could you calculate it to more decimal places?) And is it constructed out of [$\pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi), [$e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29), [$\gamma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant), etc, or is it a whole new number?

Comment: Can you show more digits? Just out of curiosity :)

Comment: @ZettaSuro I'd like to have more :( That is why I am asking this queestion!

Comment: It's just a number... there's plenty of them. Numbers that we give a name to are not just weird transcendental quantities, we remember them because they have applications! By the way, what's $k$?

Comment: strange, I get  1.1949070080264606820 using Pari/GP with 200 digits precision and the lower limit non-zero but as small as 1e-120. Change of the lower limit even nearer to zero does not affect the above shown decimal digits...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I'll edit that. And why didn't you put that as aan answer? It would have been great!

Comment: Please look also at http://fr.sci.maths.narkive.com/z7epEAu3/cherche-valeur-de-x-dans-l-equation-suivante for an additional discussion (sorry, it is in french)

Comment: @anonymousPi: ;-), well I've no (better) algebraic expression for that number - and what's what I understood your question was about...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I just found an awesome inverse calculator, I put my number to about 8 digits, and it gave nothing. Here is the link: http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the Newton-iteration I computed this to about 200 digits using Pari/GP with 200 digits float-precision. The formula to be iterated, say, 10 to 20 times, goes
$$ x_{m+1} = x_m - { \int_0^{x_m} t^t dt - 1 \over x_m^{x_m} } \qquad \qquad \text{initializing } x_0=1$$
This gives $x_{20} \sim 
 1.1949070080264606819835589994757229370314006804 \\
 \qquad  736144499162269650773566266768950014200599457247 \\
 \qquad  787580258584233234409032116176621553214684894972 \\
 \qquad  73271827683782385863978986910763464541103507567 ... $

where further iterations don't affect the shown decimals.

---

**[update]** Perhaps it is of interest to find the number $k$ where the integral does not equal $1$ but $k$ itself instead. We get for
$$ \int_0^k x^x dx = k \qquad \qquad \to \qquad k \sim  1.54431721079037838813184037292... 
$$ [/update]

---

The pari/GP code used was

```
m=1  \\ initialize 
     \\ iterate the next two commands until err is sufficiently small
err=(intnum(t=1e-160,m,t^t)-1)/(m^m)
m=precision(m-err,200)
```

Comment: Very cool!  One thing: When I compute the integral from $0$ to your $x_{20}$, I get $1.0\ldots 0999\ldots$ with 120 zeros before other stuff arises.  Should your `t=1e-120` be `t=1e-200`?  I don't know pari/GP.

Comment: @Mark: True, sorry, I've been a bit hasty transferring my result to the answer. Using the lower bound with 1e-160 suffices to get 200 digits correct - I confirmed that also using 400 digits internal precision. *(I think, for my final result I'd in fact used the lower bound of 1e-200 which is my "standard"/default precision for such tasks, but where I had stepped to 1e-60,1e-80 and then 1e-120 for the lower bound to improve speed of computation.)*

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Told you it would be a good idea to answer!

By the way, I upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

Wolfram Alpha [thinks](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x%5Ex+from+0+to+1.19491) that $k=1.19491$ exactly.  I'm sure that's only a rounding artifact, but funny nevertheless.  This was found in about 5 minutes via bisection, i.e. trying $1.2, 1.19, 1.195, \ldots$.

Comment: Maybe I wrote it wrong...

Comment: Well, it *knows* (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_0^{1.19491}++x^x+dx++-1), there is an error from the 6'th digit on, but WA *doesn't* document this. If you ask the integral *minus 1* you get the result: $ \int_0^{1.19491} x^x  dx  -1 = 3.7014x10^{-6} $

Comment: Try [integral of x^x from 0 to 1.19491 to 20 digits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x^x+from+0+to+1.19491+to+20+digits)

Comment: I didn't downvote, by the way!  I definitely see doing the bisection as worthwhile.